# Linq DefaultValues on Join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the total download count of my app for the last 30 days on different devices, i succeeded of returning the right query, by grouping by the number of days and joinning with an enumerable with the last thirty days. However I'm not able to format the output as i want. Let me share the query first with the presentation in LinqPad

```
var last_days = (from idx in Enumerable.Range(1, (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)).Days)
select new { day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).AddDays(idx).Date});

var orders = (from od in Orders
group od by EntityFunctions.AddSeconds((DateTime?)new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0), (int?)od.Created) into g
select new { 
    day = g.Key ,
    web = g.Where( q => q.Source == "web").Count(),
    ios = g.Where( q => q.Source == "ios").Count(),
    android = g.Where( q => q.Source == "android").Count(),
    total = g.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(q => q.day).Take(31);

var days= 
(from d in last_days
join od in orders on d.day equals od.day into x
from od in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
select x );

days.Dump();
```

This is the result I get

[image]

Now, I want to format the final output to an IEnumerable of 5 columns(day, web, ios, android, total) regardless whether it was empty or not. So instead of the empty O sign, I get the date, and the web = ios = android = total = 0. How can I  do this?
So on  day without any downloads, I still get an entry with the date and platforms to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right, generated sql is okay in complexity, was a bit rusty on linq i guess

```
var last_days = (from idx in Enumerable.Range(1, (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31)).Days)
select new { day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31).AddDays(idx).Date});

var orders = (from od in Orders
where od.ServiceProviderID == 2
group od by new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0).AddSeconds(od.Created).Date into g
select new { 
    day = (DateTime)g.Key ,
    web = g.Where( q => q.Source == "web").Count(),
    ios = g.Where( q => q.Source == "ios").Count(),
    android = g.Where( q => q.Source == "android").Count(),
    total = g.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(q => q.day).Take(32);

var days = (from d in last_days
join od in orders on d.day.Date equals od.day.Date into x
from od in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { 
    day = d.day ,
    web = (od == null) ? 0: od.web,
    ios = (od == null) ? 0: od.ios,
    android = (od == null) ? 0: od.android,
    total = (od == null) ? 0 : od.total
    } );

days.Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is hardly the most elegant solution, but something like this should work:

```
var days = last_days.Select(d =>
  orders.DefaultIfEmpty(new {
    day = d,
    web = 0,
    ios = 0,
    android = 0,
    total = 0
  }).FirstOrDefault(od =>
    od.day == d.Date));
```

The basic idea is to tell the generator what to fall back on, in each case, if an appropriate order entry cannot be found.

---

In retrospect, it's probably easier to start from a blank slate. What about something more like:

```
var last_30_days =
  from idx in Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
  orderby idx descending
  select DateTime.Now.AddDays(idx - 30).Date;

var orders =
  from date in last_30_days
  let datesOrders = Orders.Where(order => order.Created == date)
  select new Info()
  {
    Date = date,
    Web = datesOrders.Where(q => q.Source == "web").Count(),
    iOS = datesOrders.Where(q => q.Source == "ios").Count(),
    Android = datesOrders.Where(q => q.Source == "android").Count(),
    Total = datesOrders.Count()
  };
```

Comment: I got this errpr _'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'_ on the orders part. If I remove the DefaultIfEmpty lamda expression I kinda get what I had in mind but now the query take 10 seconds and the generated sql is 1400 lines.

Comment: Well, I guess that would be a pretty strong argument for not making those queries respond with anonymous types. Have you tried making a simple struct to hold the hits?

Comment: thanks Andrew, the only slight complication i have is the order.Created field is stored in a unixtimestamp, i got it working below, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting new DaySum { ord = (ord == null ? 0 : ord.Count) };

Instead of just

Select x

Comment: hmm what is the DaySum object?

Comment: You can name these anonymous types.  DaySum is my idea of what each row of this collection would be, a daily summary.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you need to declare that class first.  I think this is what I ran into when trying to declare the return type of a function as an anonymous type.